# is it possible to search only a files that have specific extended attributes set?

Tags: linux, permissions, find, grep, attributes

is it possible to search file in the linux OS that have particular extended attribute as this: `---S--l---`

```
---S--l---  1  root    root          0 Mar  1004:25/opt/csTuner/iba/wys/tuer_lolk
```

What is **S** in the permissions:

S - the changes are written synchronously on the disk; this is equivalent to the `sync' mount option applied to a subset of the files.

My goal is to search a files that  are written synchronously on the disk.

Comment: Are you sure about the meaning of S flag? As far as i read linux permissions documentation this is SUID flag

Comment: yes I want to search only this kind of files ,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` can't search for file attributes (this is something else then permissions!) on it's own.

One way:

```
find /location -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 lsattr | grep '^...S'
```

On my system, the `S` is in the third column of the `lsattr` output, so to make it more flexible, we can use a more complicated regular expression:

```
find /location -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 lsattr | grep '^[^ S]*S[^ S]* '
```

where `grep '^[^ S]*S[^ S]* '` is supposed to find anything that has an `S` in the first column.

Comment: I learnt about the `-exec command {} +` syntax while writing up my answer. It seems to be equivalent to `xargs` + pipe chaining

Comment: @tucuxi: `xargs` is much more effective if you have a large number of results, as `-exec` will spawn a new process for every file found, while `xargs` handles them in bulk. While this doesn't work for every possible command you might want to execute, it can make a dramatic difference in most cases when you get thousands of results.

Comment: It may be slower, but it should be safer: if the number of results is large (as in over `ARG_MAX`), then `xargs` will not be able to pass the full output of `find` to `lsattr`, and you will lose results. I have not tested this; going by  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit

Comment: @tucuxi Nice catch, but naturally `xargs` knows about this issue and spawns multiple processes if the command line would get too long. You still end up with a dramatically reduced number of forked processes.

Comment: Hmm - you are right. I was just editing my comment to say this. Learning a lot today...

Comment: Be sure to add -print0 to your find command and -0 to your xargs command so that you don't run into issues with files containing spaces in their names.